# Pipeline.fit() got multiple values for argument 'text_input'

Tags: prompt

I would like to do MultiLabel Text-Classification with promptify.

I got this error

```
`Pipeline.fit() got multiple values for argument 'text_input'`
```

My code:

```
model = OpenAI(api_key)
prompter = Prompter('multilabel_classification.jinja')
pipe = Pipeline(prompter, model)

classes = ['Medicine','Oncology','Metastasis','Breast cancer','Lung cancer','Cerebrospinal fluid','Tumor microenvironment','Single-cell RNA sequencing','Idiopathic intracranial hypertension']

sent = "The patient is a 93-year-old female with a medical history of chronic right hip pain, osteoporosis, hypertension, depression, and chronic atrial fibrillation admitted for evaluation and management of severe nausea and vomiting and urinary tract infection"
result = pipe.fit('multilabel_classification.jinja',
n_output_labels = len(classes),
domain = 'Clinical',
text_input = sent,
labels = classes)

print(eval(result['text']))
```

Thank you for taking the time to respond to me.

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this error is because of the `Pipeline.fit()` function treat the **first argument** as the **text_input** by default. So, the string `'multilabel_classification.jinja'` is assigned to the **text_input** parameter. Your `pipe.fit()` should look like this:

```
result = pipe.fit(n_output_labels = len(classes), 
                  domain = 'Clinical', 
                  text_input = sent, labels = classes)
```

Kindly look at the `Pipeline` source code:
[image: Source code]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your answer and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.